# Cannot Install Cocoapods - No podfile found in the project directory

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, cocoapods

I downloaded a sample project to learn how to make a UIPageViewController, and I am trying to essentially fork that project and need to add a third-party library. Right now, it does not look like I have a .xcworkspace file in my project. When I try and install the cocoapods, I first run

`sudo gem install cocoapods` - in the specific project directory in my terminal

`pod install` - in that same directory

I am receiving an error in the terminal "No podfile found in the project directory."

Is this happening because I don't have a .xcworkspace file? Am I installing the podfile correctly?

[image]

Comment: You need to have a Podfile in the directory. Checkout Cocoapods help at https://cocoapods.org

Answer (score 137, accepted):

### Steps to add CocoaPods to manage dependencies in your project:

1. `sudo gem install cocoapods` -> This installs CocoaPods as a piece
   of software on your machine.
2. Go to the root of your project directory and execute `pod init` ->
   This will add a base Podfile to your project.
3. Add the external dependencies that you have to this Podfile by editing it.
4. Run `pod install` which will fetch all the external dependencies
   mentioned by you, and associate it with a `.xcworkspace` file of
   your project. This `.xcworkspace` file will be generated for you if
   you already do not have one.

From here on, you should use `.xcworkspace` file instead of `.xcproject` / `.xcodeproj`.

### Example Podfile Syntax:

```
target 'MyApp' do   
pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 3.0'
end
```

Where `AFNetworking` is the pod and `3.0` is the specific version that I want to install.

Documentation: [Using CocoaPods](https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/using-cocoapods.html)

Comment: Can you elaborate on Step 3? I have opened the podfile, and see several items stating target 'App name' followed by 'do' then 'end'. Can I delete this code?

Comment: Do not delete that code. A Podfile is ruby based. The 'App name' you see here is your `target name`. Inside the `do` and `end` for a target, you mention the pods that you want to add to install to it.

Comment: how much time it will take for first time pod install?

Comment: @GvSharma The first time pod install is known to take time as it clones the CocoaPods master spec repo. You can add the argument `--verbose` while running `pod install` to see what's exactly happening.

Comment: "From here on, you should use .xcworkspace file instead of .xcproject". Big thanks for that clarification, I had been confused earlier about it. And no other tutorial had mentioned that.

Comment: If you are using flutter, make sure you are in the ios folder before `pod init`

Comment: If you're using Flutter, in the terminal `cd ios` then `pod install`

Answer (score 17):

Just posting for anyone that encountered this issue while working on a react native project.

1. `sudo gem install cocoapods`
   this installs cocoa pods to your machine
2. `cd projectDirectory` cd into your project directory
3. `cd ios` cd into the ios directory of your project, is you list items that are in this folder, you would most likely see a podfile there.
4. `pod install`

Comment: Yes, I have to `cd ios` to be able to run `pod install`... smh

Answer (score 9):

If you want to add a library from GitHub to your own project, after installing gems, do firstly `pod init` look at from GitHub cocoapod description and then add it after target line in podfile.

Save and run "pod install".

It would be successfully added on your project.

Answer (score 8):

Don't forget to call `pod install` in the Project folder of your project (not in the root).

Answer (score 2):

Open a terminal, if you use VSCode, you can just run the following from the terminal
Do a `cd <project_name>` to your flutter project directory
Run `cd iOS`
Then run `pod install`

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it