# 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, flutter-packages, flutter-ios

[image]

How fixed this problem ?
Android work fine.
But IOS doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is:

1. `rm ios/Flutter/Flutter.podspec`
2. `flutter clean`
3. `flutter run`

taken from [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/70895#issuecomment-744734693)

Comment: @ErayHamurlu check https://stackoverflow.com/a/67110794/8647537