# Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found

Tags: ios, flutter, firebase

I am developing the app with flutter, I am getting this error: 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found, this error when I build the ios app. How can I solve it?

Comment: Show your Podfile content

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67922024/flutter-flutter-h-file-not-found