# File not found Flutter/Flutter.h in xcode flutter project 2.5.2

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oWLm6.jpg)

I am continuously getting Flutter/Flutter.h file not found issue after build for iOS on x code

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64973346/error-flutter-flutter-h-file-not-found-when-flutter-run-on-ios/65577277

Comment: Check out 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/67110794/8647537