# I am run my old flutter project and i am facing 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found error

Tags: flutter, xcode

i am using dart 1.22.6 old flutter version and x code version is 13.2.

i am not facing any error in this project but while i am try to run this app in simulator so i am found this types of error.

```
    Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 11 in debug mode...
main.dart:1
Xcode build done.                                           44.3s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    --- xcodebuild: WARNING: Using the first of multiple matching destinations:
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:dvtdevice-DVTiOSDeviceSimulatorPlaceholder-iphonesimulator:placeholder, name:Any iOS Simulator Device }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:104209BD-52E3-4110-B838-1BF38B4F8BCB, OS:15.2, name:iPad (9th generation) }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:7A8C8BB3-0ECB-4532-B038-53FE9F079FC0, OS:15.2, name:iPad Air (4th generation) }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:9FE5A995-89FD-43D1-8505-A94CEE3097F2, OS:15.2, name:iPad Pro (9.7-inch) }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:44B14EDE-BEF3-47B6-B478-E65E0F75941F, OS:15.2, name:iPad Pro (11-inch) (3rd generation) }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:AF43CF8F-BB27-4516-9E6F-46072425EF9B, OS:15.2, name:iPad Pro (12.9-inch) (5th generation) }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:9572BFCB-67D7-4712-8B5A-E5706C461250, OS:15.2, name:iPad mini (6th generation) }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:FD8861C3-B09E-42CB-9818-12DBCCEA9C55, OS:15.2, name:iPhone 6s }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:DC179C53-C6C9-4F2B-9E09-25ADF83F4F4E, OS:15.2, name:iPhone 8 }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:2C9EBB64-5221-4890-9C76-118D65C5A84B, OS:15.2, name:iPhone 8 Plus }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:A74AA3B0-B04C-4668-A0D0-C839C258EC4C, OS:15.2, name:iPhone 11 }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:350009C2-7A8C-41F4-9655-120D7BE923F0, OS:15.2, name:iPhone 11 Pro }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:C821BC5B-9DAC-4842-91E2-FC918DBD80E9, OS:15.2, name:iPhone 11 Pro Max }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:1AC7F3A9-76D2-4E52-9287-6706FB7C388E, OS:15.2, name:iPhone 12 }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:F79FF7B2-FC2A-42B6-ADC5-B5301C127504, OS:15.2, name:iPhone 12 Pro }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:80718B29-3D3B-4EF2-B183-747E40D4C36A, OS:15.2, name:iPhone 12 Pro Max }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:5F81412E-04BD-4F09-AE30-D33DEC5A332D, OS:15.2, name:iPhone 12 mini }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:4AAA78B7-2A08-4409-A483-B4FAF81C8784, OS:15.2, name:iPhone 13 }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:A1BE4D56-8544-4013-AD13-C68DFCBE3A93, OS:15.2, name:iPhone 13 Pro }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:F118EFA7-B808-467B-8970-E327DE0C23FD, OS:15.2, name:iPhone 13 Pro Max }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:B2EA48C5-FA93-4AA9-9232-BE81C8033248, OS:15.2, name:iPhone 13 mini }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:80C5C6A5-D94E-4923-9F75-F69C8663FB63, OS:15.2, name:iPhone SE (2nd generation) }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:576B135F-6377-4BC2-BAA6-494716693933, OS:15.2, name:iPod touch (7th generation) }
    { platform:iOS, id:dvtdevice-DVTiPhonePlaceholder-iphoneos:placeholder, name:Any iOS Device }
    ** BUILD FAILED **
Xcode's output:
↳
    ld: warning: object file (/Users/sarvadhi/Downloads/mobile-Unique/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Pods_NotificationService.framework/Pods_NotificationService(Pods-NotificationService-dummy.o)) was built for newer iOS Simulator version (15.0) than being linked (14.0)
    ld: warning: object file (/Users/sarvadhi/Downloads/mobile-Unique/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Pods_NotificationService.framework/Pods_NotificationService(Pods_NotificationService_vers.o)) was built for newer iOS Simulator version (15.0) than being linked (14.0)
    /Users/sarvadhi/Downloads/mobile-Unique/ios/Runner/AppDelegate.swift:3:8: error: no such module 'flutter_local_notifications'
    import flutter_local_notifications
           ^
    note: Using new build system
    note: Planning
    note: Build preparation complete
    note: Building targets in dependency order

    Could not build the application for the simulator.

    Error launching application on iPhone 11.

   Exited (sigterm)
```

After open this project in xCode so i can see this error in **GenratedPliginRegistrant** file.

This is a **GenratedPliginRegistrant** code

```
//
//  Generated file. Do not edit.
//

#ifndef GeneratedPluginRegistrant_h
#define GeneratedPluginRegistrant_h

#import <Flutter/Flutter.h>

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN

@interface GeneratedPluginRegistrant : NSObject
+ (void)registerWithRegistry:(NSObject<FlutterPluginRegistry>*)registry;
@end

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END
#endif /* GeneratedPluginRegistrant_h */
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter.h not found error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50671286/flutter-h-not-found-error)

Comment: Thank you for the support. i try to this method but this is not working for me.