# How to address error installing cocoapods (undefined method `invoke_with_build_args' for nil:NilClass)?

Tags: cocoa, cocoapods

I run

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

but I receive the following error. I'm trying to follow the instructions at [Cannot Install Cocoapods - No podfile found in the project directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36902497/cannot-install-cocoapods-no-podfile-found-in-the-project-directory) but am getting stuck because I can't get past this step.

Any advice on what I would do?

```
ERROR:  Loading command: install (LoadError)
    dlopen(/Users/sharatakasapu/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin16/openssl.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/sharatakasapu/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin16/openssl.bundle
  Reason: image not found - /Users/sharatakasapu/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin16/openssl.bundle
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)
    undefined method `invoke_with_build_args' for nil:NilClass
```

Comment: Did you manage to solve this?

Answer (score 3):

I was finally able to move forward using info from this site to simply upgrade to a new version of `rbenv`:
https://qiita.com/nya__str/items/eeddac3a122f0c251d88

```
# view versions available to install
rbenv install --list

# pick the latest version from the list and install it
rbenv install 2.7.2

# set as the new default
rbenv global 2.7.2

# try again
sudo gem install cocoapods

#
```

Comment: Before `rbenv install 2.7.2`
run the following to upgrade ruby-build by running
`brew update && brew upgrade ruby-build`

Comment: Thanks it worked!!