# My AppCenter fails with error "No `Podfile' found in the project directory" and my project does not use cocoapods

Tags: ios, react-native, cocoapods, visual-studio-app-center

I have a React Native (v0.59) project and I'm trying to compile the iOS version on AppCenter and I keep getting this error:

`No 'Podfile' found in the project directory`.

I'm not using cocoapods on my project, so why am I getting this errors?

I did a `pod init` on it, because I was trying something. But I already deleted the podfile and did a `pod deintegrate` and `pod clean`.

Can someone help me?

Comment: May be this answer will be helpful to you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36903181/10969195

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you didn't run `react-native link` or so. [Here's](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/sdk/getting-started/react-native#32-integrate-the-sdk-automatically-for-react-native-lower-than-060) a good explanation.

You can also try integrating without CocoaPods at all, please see [these instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/sdk/getting-started/react-native#33-ios-only-integrate-the-sdk-manually-for-react-native-without-react-native-link-or-cocoapods).