# Unable to build and run react native project. Pods failing to install

Tags: firebase, react-native, podfile, pod-install

I am currently getting the following error when running pod install:

[image]

Do I need to update the OpenSSL-Universal? If so, how do I do this? I am also using Firebase. Is this an issue? Does Firebase need to be updated? My project was building and running earlier. Not sure what has happened now. Can someone please assist? Thank you.

Please see Pod File below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add the below to your pod file

```
pod 'OpenSSL-Universal', '~>1.1.180'
```

NOTE: after adding this, just running pod install will fire an error due to versions mismatch, in that case remove Podfile.lock and pod install again

Comment: Thanks for your response. Unfortunately, running 'pod install --repo-update' gives me the same error. Also, when running 'pod update Firebase/Core' I get the error: No `Podfile.lock' found in the project directory, run `pod install'.

Comment: This link doesn't seem to help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36902497/cannot-install-cocoapods-no-podfile-found-in-the-project-directory

Comment: Can someone please assist? Thanks

Comment: Did you try adding pod 'OpenSSL-Universal', '~>1.1.180 to your pod file? I am editing my answer, try that once

Comment: It's still throwing the error above after running pod install. I actually don't have Podfile.lock in my iOS folder.

Comment: No, I built my project again.